# Postgresql - what does % and <%> mean?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to explore RDkit cartridge on Postgresql. I've installed RDkit on Postgresql and now am trying to go through the documentation at http://rdkit.org/docs_temp/Cartridge.html. Here when trying to understand the similarity search, I've come across the below code. But I'm unable to understand it fully as I'm totally new to both Postgresql and RDkit.

```
chembl_23=# create or replace function get_mfp2_neighbors(smiles text)
    returns table(molregno integer, m mol, similarity double precision) as
  $$
  select molregno,m,tanimoto_sml(morganbv_fp(mol_from_smiles($1::cstring)),mfp2) as similarity
  from rdk.fps join rdk.mols using (molregno)
  where morganbv_fp(mol_from_smiles($1::cstring))%mfp2
  order by morganbv_fp(mol_from_smiles($1::cstring))<%>mfp2;
  $$ language sql stable ;
```

My questions are -

1) What does %mfp2 mean in WHERE clause? *- I've searched on Google and stumbled upon pages where it's mentioned that it's LIKE %% operator in SQL. But here LIKE operator is not used, still is the meaning same?*

2) What does <%>mfp2 mean in ORDER BY clause? *- I'm clueless about this operator.*

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: `<%> : used for Tanimoto KNN searches (to return ordered lists of neighbors).` It is an extension to the type- and operator- system: UDTs. So is `cstring`, so it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those operators are defined by RDkit, they have no inherent meaning to PostgreSQL itself (with the datatypes being used). You will find them documented within the context of RDkit on that page you linked to.  Other extensions have operators with the same "spelling" (but different argument types) but used in other ways.

> `%`: operator used for similarity searches using Tanimoto similarity.
>   Returns whether or not the Tanimoto similarity between two
>   fingerprints (either two sfp or two bfp values) exceeds
>   rdkit.tanimoto_threshold.
>
> `<%>`:
>   used for Tanimoto KNN searches (to return ordered lists of neighbors).

mfp2 is the name of a column, so `%mfp2` would be more clearly written with space `someconstant % mfp2`

Comment: `%`  does have a meaning in Postgres. It's the [modulo operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html)